# How to group by time and if there is no data count as zero in mysql?

Tags: mysql

sql query is

```
select substring(InputTime, 1, 13) as Time, count(*) as count from DB group by hour(InputTime);
```

and it comes out

```
+---------------+-------+
| Time          | count |
+---------------+-------+
| 2021-06-15 01 |    11 |
| 2021-06-15 02 |    22 |
| 2021-06-15 04 |    22 |
+---------------+-------+
```

But I want to

```
+---------------+-------+
| Time          | count |
+---------------+-------+
| 2021-06-15 01 |    11 |
| 2021-06-15 02 |    22 |
| 2021-06-15 03 |    0  |
| 2021-06-15 04 |    22 |
| 2021-06-15 05 |    0  |
...
...
...
...
...
+---------------+-------+
```

So I want to fill empty count with value zero.
How to edit my query?

Comment: Generate base times/calendar table and leftjoin your data to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, your query can be expressed in a simpler way as:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCalls, HOUR(`end`) AS `Hour`
FROM callsDataTable c
INNER JOIN products p ON c.company = p.number
AND p.id IN (@_PRODUCTS)
AND YEAR(`end`) = @_YEAR AND MONTH(`end`) = @_MONTH
GROUP BY HOUR(`end`) AS `Hour`
ORDER BY `Hour` ASC

2. Using the idea suggested by @NoDisplayName in their answer:

CREATE TABLE hours_table (hours INT);

INSERT INTO hours_table VALUES(0), (1), (2),
/* put the missing values here */ (23);

3. You can join the table that contains the hours to get the results you want:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCalls, h.hours AS `Hour`
FROM callsDataTable c
INNER JOIN products p ON c.company = p.number
RIGHT JOIN hours_table h ON h.hours = HOUR(c.`end`)
AND p.id IN (@_PRODUCTS)
AND YEAR(`end`) = @_YEAR AND MONTH(`end`) = @_MONTH
GROUP BY h.hours
ORDER BY h.hours ASC

4. If it runs too slow (and I'm sure it is very slow) you should investigate a way to use something like end BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-31 23:59:59' instead of comparing YEAR(end) and MONTH(end).
5. It can be accomplished like this:

SET @start = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@_YEAR, '-', @_MONTH, '-01 00:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
SET @end   = DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 SECOND);

SELECT ...
...
AND `end` BETWEEN @start AND @end
...

6. But this change doesn't help by itself. It needs an index on field end to bring the desired speed improvement:

ALTER TABLE callsDataTable ADD INDEX(end);

7. Using HOUR(c.end) in the join condition is another reason to run slowly.

It can be improved by joining the table hours_table with the result set produced by the (simplified version of the) first query:

SELECT IFNULL(totalCalls, 0) AS totalCalls, h.hours AS `Hour`
FROM hours_table h
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCalls, HOUR(`end`) as `Hour`
FROM callsDataTable c
INNER JOIN products p ON c.company = p.number
AND p.id IN (@_PRODUCTS)
AND YEAR(`end`) = @_YEAR AND MONTH(`end`) = @_MONTH
GROUP BY HOUR(`end`) AS `Hour`
) d ON h.hours = d.`Hour`
ORDER BY h.hours ASC